# Why is my xpath parser only scraping the first dozen elements in a table?

Tags: html, web-scraping, xpath

I'm learning how to interact with websites via python and I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-rotate-proxies-and-ip-addresses-using-python-3/).

I wanted to know how `xpath` worked which led me [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20-ways-write-ultimate-xpath-any-type-web-element-never-adnan-arif/).

I've made some adjustments to the code from the origional site to select elements if multiple conditions are met.

However, in both the origional code from the tutorial and my own update I seem to be only grabbing a small section of the body. I was under the impression `xpath('//tbody/tr')[:10]:` would grab the entire body and allow me to interact with 10 in this case columns.

At time of writing when I run the code it retuns 2 hits, while if I do the same thing with a manual copy and paste to excel I get 94 hits.

Why am I only able to parse a few lines from the table and not all lines?

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

def get_proxies():
    url = 'https://free-proxy-list.net/'
    response = requests.get(url)
    parser = fromstring(response.text)
    proxies = set()
    for i in parser.xpath('//tbody/tr')[:10]:
        if i.xpath('.//td[7][contains(text(),"yes")]') and i.xpath('.//td[5][contains(text(),"elite")]'):
            # Grabbing IP and corresponding PORT
            proxy = ":".join([i.xpath('.//td[1]/text()')[0], i.xpath('.//td[2]/text()')[0]])
            proxies.add(proxy)
    return proxies

proxies = get_proxies()
print(proxies)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: `[:10]` refers not to columns but to rows.

Changing 10 to 20, 50 or 100, check 10, 20, 50 or 100 rows.